# Easier differentiating between viewed and un-viewed questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

I don't know about you guys, but I have a difficult time telling the difference between the blue text of an un-viewed question and the *slightly* lighter blue text of a viewed one.

Should I just pay more attention, or would there be a better color scheme to help show which questions you've looked at already?

Perhaps a grey color would be easier to make out than the lighter blue.

Here is what things look like for me:
[image]
They all kind of blend together.

Comment: Yes, out of the millions of visitors we've ever had, you're the only person who's ever had this problem.

Comment: I knew it... I'm so alone in this vast, empty world of internets!

Comment: The answer is to create a custom CSS tag. How you'd actually go about doing so is well beyond my understanding or capability.

Comment: Your monitor might have messed-up color settings; viewed questions are quite a bit lighter for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create add some custom CSS for the site.

This can usually be done with a browser extension: [Stylebot for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en), [Stylish for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/). Google around for your browser of choice.

I think you need to add the following rule (adjust the colour to your preference):

```
.question-hyperlink:visited {
    color: #bbb !important;
}
```

This recolours any links to a question that you’ve already visited in a very light shade of grey.

Here’s what that looks like in my browser:

[image]

If you wanted, you could choose an even lighter shade of grey to make them fade away even more.

Comment: This may sort-of clash with the ignored tags (if you've set ignored tags to be 'greyed-out' instead of 'hidden').

Comment: @Mooz You can change the `bbb` to any color you want [using the codes generated here](http://www.colorpicker.com/).  For example, `00FF22` for bright green.  (`bbb` means the same as `bbbbbb`, upper/lowercase doesn't matter)